# Sign of an Infinite Prime

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

What is the sign of an infinite prime?

I'm reading ch. II of Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* without a background in class field theory. On the bottom of page 155, Silverman writes $\text{sign}(N_s)=\text{sign}(s_\infty)$ and I am unclear on what is meant here.

Further, if anybody is feeling up to it, does the sign of an infinite prime relate to the reciprocity map, and if so how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\sigma : K \to \mathbb{R}$ is a real embedding then for $\alpha \in K$ you can look at $\text{sign}(\sigma(\alpha))$. It is useful to make sense to $(\alpha) \equiv 1 \bmod^* \mathfrak{M}$ (for the kernel of the Artin map)

Comment: So in the instance Silverman uses this we are looking at the idele group $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}^*$ so we need only worry about the one real place. However, I'm still confused since if $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the real place it must take -1 to -1 and so there is nothing too interesting going on. Further, looking at $\text{sign}(\alpha)$ seems to depend on $\alpha$. So I guess we'd rectify this by making a real extension $K$ simple, say $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, and then looking at where the real places take $\theta$?

Comment: Yes $(\alpha) \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ depends on $\alpha$, that's why we restrict to a particular $\alpha$ by saying $\sigma(\alpha) > 0$. To see why we care of $(\alpha) \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{M}$ you should look at the Artin map (and its kernel) of a cyclotomic extension $K(\zeta_n)/K$ of a number field.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of other confused grad students, I will further explain my confusion. I'm essentially restating reuns answer in less precise terms.

In *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* we are considering an idele $s\in \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}^*$. There is only one real place and we require $N_s$ has the same sign as $s_\infty$, the entry in the component of $s$ representing the real place.

Generally, we don't allow a modulus to contain any complex places, so we don't need to worry about them. Intuitively, $\text{sign}(α)$ being positive is the equivalent of $\alpha$ being congruent to 1 modulo $\mathfrak{p}^{v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{m})}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal and $\mathfrak{m}$ is our modulus.

I found Sutherland's notes http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes20.pdf to be very concise and helpful.